# Swift show alert in MFMailComposeViewController didFinishWith result

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, alert

I want to present an alert when the user cancels the Email. For this I use following code:

```
func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {

    if result == .cancelled {

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "E-Mail not sent!", message: "E-Mail not sent.", preferredStyle: .alert)

        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
        }))

        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

The function is called and the Mail View is dismissed, but no alert is presented. I use this code inside a UITableViewController. Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show the alertController inside the completionBlock.

```
controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
if result == .cancelled {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "E-Mail not sent!", message: "E-Mail not sent.", preferredStyle: .alert)

        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
        }))

        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
})
```

like this..

Comment: So easy...Thanks :)